# EVM430F6779 electric meter interface to serial terminal

Tags: microcontroller, rs232

I want to interface EVM430F6779 electric meter to serial terminal.

I have already interfaced with the GUI using rs232 to my computer and i am  getting the desired results

I then did some research on DL/T645 and i am able to communicate with meter for getting phase1, phase2 and phase3 readings through serial terminal.

STEP1: I open GUI and wait for the signal to turn green

STEP2: I colse GUI and open serial terminal, configure COM and baudrate and then i send the code for phase1,phase2 and phase3 readings

The problem i am facing is i am not able to communicate directly by opening the serial terminal. First i have to open GUI and once the signal is green i close GUI, open serial terminal and then communicate for meter readings.

If i bypass STEP1 and directly go to STEP2 i dont get any response from the meter. I guess there is some password set in the meter for enabling the communication and when i open GUI the password is sent by GUI and communication is triggered.

Do we really have any password? if yes please let me know the initial command that should be given to trigger communication.

If there is no password then how should i bypass step1?

My goal is to open serial terminal and start communication with the meter without any dependency of GUI.

Please solve my above problems. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you read the firmware code yet?

Comment: @Vijay: Where are the links to the datasheets for all the devices you have mentioned?

Comment: Hi iganacio, I am reading the firmware and doing reverse engineering of the password. Its time consuming, if i could get the password then it will be helpful for me to proceed.

Comment: Hi Transistor, sorry i forgot to post link http://www.ti.com/tool/EVM430-F6779

Comment: @Transistor - Hi - Just FYI, this question is related to the OP's previous EE.SE question [here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/261243/) and the duplicates of these 2 questions asked on the TI E2E site [here](https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/msp430/f/166/t/545698) and [here](https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/msp430/f/166/t/546903).

Comment: Hi sam, yes those are my posts only. Hunting for answers. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am done with the interface, i interfaced the TI meter to serial utility.
Please refer to the below provided links for answer.
If you have any questions or problems please reply in this thread. I will help you with answers. Cheers!!

https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/msp430/f/166/t/520026

https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/msp430/f/166/t/546903